# Jquery rotate pictures in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

In my page i have a list that i use Jquery's rotate method for and works correctly in Firefox but not in Chrome.

**Firefox**:

[image]

**Chrome**:

[image]

As you see in pictures in chrome box of first image is empty and it is show in second box.

HTML:

```
            <div class="m-main-tbl m-b-s">
                <div>
                    <span class="m-main-image"><img id="big-img" src="images/cute-baby.png"/></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="m-main-more-info">
                        <p class="title m-p1"><a class="m-a1" href="#">Clothes</a></p>
                        <p class="info m-p3">
                            <span class="p-two-2 p-green-2">3 day</span>
                            <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-ex">until end</span>
                            <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-span-m">|</span>
                            <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-green-2">450/000 $</span>
                            <span class="p-two-2">Support</span>
                            <span class="p-two-2 p-left"><a class="m-a2" href="#">More...</a></span>
                        </p>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="m-left-tbl">
                        <div class="m-box-show m-first-div">
                            <img class="m-div-image" src="images/cute-baby.thm.png"/>
                            <div class="m-first-div2">
                                <p class="title m-p1"><a class="m-a1" href="#">Clothes</a></p>
                                <p class="m-p2">Clothes for childrens</p>
                                <p class="info m-p3">
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-green-2">3 day</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-ex">until end</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-span-m">|</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-green-2">450/000</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2">Support</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-left"><a class="m-a2" href="#">More...</a></span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="m-p-last">
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2">Status</span>
                                    <div class="m-progress">
                                        <div class="m-progress-green"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="m-btn-success">Support</button>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="m-box-show m-second-div m-first-div">
                            <img class="m-div-image" src="images/image.thm.png"/>
                            <div class="m-first-div2">
                                <p class="title m-p1"><a class="m-a1" href="#">Magic Ring</a></p>
                                <p class="m-p2">Magic ring for you</p>
                                <p class="info m-p3">
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-green-2">3 day</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-ex">until end</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-span-m">|</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-green-2">450/000</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2">Support</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-left"><a class="m-a2" href="#">More...</a></span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="m-p-last">
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2">Status</span>
                                <div class="m-progress">
                                    <div class="m-progress-green"></div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="m-btn-success">Support</button>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="m-box-show m-second-div m-first-div">
                            <img class="m-div-image" src="images/image3.thm.png"/>
                            <div class="m-first-div2">
                                <p class="title m-p1"><a class="m-a1" href="#">Glasses</a></p>
                                <p class="m-p2">Glasses for you</p>
                                <p class="info m-p3">
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-green-2">3 day</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-ex">until end</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-span-m">|</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-green-2">450/000</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2">Support</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-left"><a class="m-a2" href="#">More...</a></span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="m-p-last">
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2">Status</span>
                                <div class="m-progress">
                                    <div class="m-progress-green"></div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="m-btn-success">Support</button>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="m-box-show m-second-div m-first-div">
                            <img class="m-div-image" src="images/image3.thm.png"/>
                            <div class="m-first-div2">
                                <p class="title m-p1"><a class="m-a1" href="#">Glasses</a></p>
                                <p class="m-p2">Glasses for you</p>
                                <p class="info m-p3">
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-green-2">3 day</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-ex">until end</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-span-m">|</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-green-2">450/000</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2">Support</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-left"><a class="m-a2" href="#">More...</a></span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="m-p-last">
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2">Status</span>
                                <div class="m-progress">
                                    <div class="m-progress-green"></div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="m-btn-success">Support</button>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="m-box-show m-second-div m-first-div">
                            <img class="m-div-image" src="images/image3.thm.png"/>
                            <div class="m-first-div2">
                                <p class="title m-p1"><a class="m-a1" href="#">Glasses</a></p>
                                <p class="m-p2">Glasses for you</p>
                                <p class="info m-p3">
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-green-2">3 day</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-ex">until end</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-span-m">|</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-green-2">450/000</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2">Support</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-left"><a class="m-a2" href="#">More...</a></span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="m-p-last">
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2">Status</span>
                                <div class="m-progress">
                                    <div class="m-progress-green"></div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="m-btn-success">Support</button>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="m-box-show m-second-div m-first-div">
                            <img class="m-div-image" src="images/image3.thm.png"/>
                            <div class="m-first-div2">
                                <p class="title m-p1"><a class="m-a1" href="#">Glasses</a></p>
                                <p class="m-p2">Glasses for you</p>
                                <p class="info m-p3">
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-green-2">3 day</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-ex">until end</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-span-m">|</span>
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2 p-green-2">450/000</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2">Support</span>
                                    <span class="p-two-2 p-left"><a class="m-a2" href="#">More...</a></span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="m-p-last">
                                    <span class="m-p3 p-two-2">Status</span>
                                <div class="m-progress">
                                    <div class="m-progress-green"></div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="m-btn-success">Support</button>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Jquery:

```
function rotatePics(){
    var first = $('.m-box-show:first');
    var height = first.height();

    first.fadeOut('slow', function() {
        first.detach();

        var next = $('.m-box-show:first');
        next.removeClass('m-second-div');
        next.css('margin-top', height + 'px');
        first.insertAfter('.m-box-show:last');
        next.animate({marginTop: 0}, 1000);

        first.css('margin-top', '5px');
        first.addClass('m-second-div');
        first.fadeIn();

        var more = $('.m-main-more-info');
        more.find('.title').html(next.find('.title').html());
        more.find('.info').html(next.find('.info').html());

        $('#big-img').attr('src', next.find('img').attr('src').replace('.thm',''));
    });
}
```

How can i fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Divs in spans? Seems wrong.

Comment: I agree with @Paulie_D HTML elements are not arbitrarily interchangeable. Divs in spans is like wearing your underpants outside your trousers- sure you can, but it's not very functional and people will think you look funny.

Comment: @chridam lol. Superman does ok though!. Elham,  if you can reproduce on http://jsfiddle.net/ we can have a better look, it's hard to answer without the CSS, thanks.,

Comment: @RobSedgwick LOL! Only superman and Chuck Norris :P

Comment: @Paulie_D : i change first  `span ` to  `div ` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @ElhamGdz could you please post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the problem at least we can help solve the issue when we have something tangible?

Comment: @Paulie_D: sorry , my network speed is low and i can upload my code in jsfiddle, do you want i upload css?